# Handling repeating return values, with individual messages

Tags: function, vbscript, return-value

I have this code which works perfect for me, when running just one `objShell.Run` line.

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

retval = objShell.Run ("cmd /c title Phase 1 & robocopy C:\this C:\that /MIR /L",1,True)

If retval < 0 Then
    MsgBox "cmd aborted, return value is: " & retval
ElseIf retval > 7 Then
    MsgBox "robocopy error, return value is: " & retval
Else
    MsgBox "robocopy successful, return value is: " & retval
End If
```

How would I need to go, when I want to have multiple `objShell.Run` lines?
E.g.

```
retval = objShell.Run ("cmd /c title Phase 1 & robocopy C:\this C:\that /MIR /L",1,True)
retval = objShell.Run ("cmd /c title Phase 2 & robocopy C:\thistoo C:\thattoo /MIR /L",1,True)
retval = objShell.Run ("cmd /c title Phase 3 & robocopy C:\andthis C:\andthat /MIR /L",1,True)
```

I could make each retval variable unique e.g. `retval1`, `retval2`, `retval3`
And iterate the [If..Then..Else] statement, but that feels clunky and probably not the nicest way to go.

For me the best way would be a `MsgBox` showing a "report" about each individual `objShell.Run` line, when they are finished. Except when all lines are successful, then a `MsgBox "all done"` will do just fine.

In which direction do I need to start my search? Functions, arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used that object WScript.Shell,

but having had a look at your code, sample and explanation.
I think this is what you mean?

```
'-> Initialise
SequenceSteps = 3
Result = ""
ErrString = ""
MyCommandSequence(0) = "cmd /c title Phase 1 & robocopy C:\this C:\that /MIR /L"
MyCommandSequence(1) = "cmd /c title Phase 2 & robocopy C:\thistoo C:\thattoo /MIR /L"
MyCommandSequence(2) = "cmd /c title Phase 3 & robocopy C:\andthis C:\andthat /MIR /L"

'-> Process
ErrorOccurred = False
For Counta = 0 To SequenceSteps - 1
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    retval = objShell.Run (MyCommandSequence(Counta), 1, True)
    '-> process request result
    If retval < 0 Then
        ErrString = "cmd aborted, return value is: " & retval
        '** NEW CODE LINE **
        Exit For
    ElseIf retval > 7 Then
        ErrString = "robocopy error, return value is: " & retval
        '** NEW CODE LINE **
        Exit For
    Else
        Result = Result  & "robocopy successful, return value is: " & retval & vbcrlf
    End If
Next
'-> Display Accordingly
If Trim(ErrString) <> "" Then
    MsgBox Result & vbcrlf & ErrString
Else
    MsgBox "All Done"
End if
```

## UPDATE

Re-Edited code

Comment: Current script gives a type mismatch error on 'MyCommandSequence', don't understand why.

Comment: MyCommandSequence is not declared as an array, so I added `Dim MyCommandSequence(3)` to declared a array with the size of 3

Comment: Yeah it kind of goes without saying that if you are using VB, you must declare the array before using it.... as in DIM.... If this helps you, please mark it as the answer. Thanks n Good Luck...

Comment: Unfortunately it's not exactly what i'm looking for. With the current code I don't know which Phase exited with which errorlevel, and it doesn't return a `< 0` value when closing a cmd.

Comment: I have added EXIT FOR to exit the for-next loop on an error, hopefully this should help you find where your program is bombing out.